# using aliases in function?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I have a script yummy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
alias yumy='yum install -y '
yumprovision() {
  yumy
}
```

When I run this script got this

```
bash: yumy: command not found
```

why it's not loading alias in function?

Comment: Before declaring the alias add the line `shopt -s expand_aliases` -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases

Comment: cool... thats working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the visibility issues of aliases usually only being defined in interactive shells, you apparently need to use `eval` to execute the alias **if the alias name is in a shell variable**.

#### Demonstration

Here's a simple alias:

```
$ alias testing='echo this is test'
```

Simply referencing `$this`, even without quoting, does not work:

```
$ foo() { local this=testing; $this "$@"; }
$ foo bar
testing: command not found
```

One has to use `eval` to make this work:

```
$ foo() { local this=testing; eval $this '"$@"'; }
$ foo bar
this is test bar
```

Comment: yes, because aliases are expanded _early_, before actual syntactic parsing. Which is mostly another reason not to use them, unless you want to do the sort of tricks where messing with the syntax is an advantage.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a function for `yumy` too:

```
#!/bin/bash
yumy() {
    yum install -y "$@"
}
yumprovision() {
    yumy
}
```

The `"$@"` expands to the arguments of that function, so `yumy foo bar` works the same as `yum install -y foo bar`.

Bash doesn't expand aliases in noninteractive shells by default, but you can change that with `shopt expand_aliases` if you *really* want, see [The Shopt Builtin in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html). But there's little reason to do that, functions are better in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

Because aliases cannot be used in scripts. Aliases are only "converted" when entered at the terminal (otherwise writing scripts would be difficult, because you wouldn't now how `ls` or `rm` would react, for instance).

Comment: is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Define functions... But what is the purpose of aliases in a script?

Comment: to avoid duplicates. yes using the function is possible but I have many aliases that I don't want to convert to functions.

Comment: Hmm... So there is no way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe variables are the `alias` of scripting.

You always can do the following, [But not recommended]

```
[arif@arif ~]$ yumi='yum install -y'

[arif@arif ~]$ $yumi tmux

Error: This command has to be run under the root user.
```

Why this method is not recommended and which way to follow is [discussed at this link.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/171196)